# Deploy the Static Azure WebApp from Dropbox

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have a Linux based Webapp and I am trying to deploy this static webapp deployment from dropbox and after I navigate to the Deployment Center, there is no option for Dropbox or OneDrive. What are the possible ways to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is Linux WebApp, it is currently not available. Because these deployment options are only available for Windows Web Apps, not for Linux Web Apps.

There are other current limitations on Linux platform:

1. App Service on Linux is not supported on Shared pricing tier.
   2.You can't mix Windows and Linux apps in the same App Service plan.
2. Within the same resource group, you can't mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region.
3. The Azure portal shows only features that currently work for Linux apps. As features are enabled, they're activated on the portal.
4. When deployed to built-in images, your code and content are allocated a storage volume for web content, backed by Azure Storage. The disk latency of this volume is higher and more variable than the latency of the container filesystem. Apps that require heavy read-only access to content files may benefit from the custom container option, which places files in the container filesystem instead of on the content volume.

Please take a look at this doc for more info : [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#app-service-on-linux)